How to use module in terraform? Facing some error in Glue CICD job pipeline
In my AWS Glue job CICD pipeline, I have created a separate folders(modules) for each job and placed the job relevant artifacts inside each folders.
Please find the below structure of the repo.
tf_prj_1\-------------------------------------> Application name
| |tf_json_job/-------------------------------> Job Name as folder (First Job)
| |--|sf_login.py---------------------  |
| |--|terraform_comments.py |
| |--|terraform_list.py     |
| |--|tf_json_job_int.json      |--------> First job artifacts with config file
| |--|tf_json_job_sf.json       |
| |--|tf_json_job.tf        |
| |--|variables.tf--------------------- |
| |--|tf_python_job/-------------------------> Job Name as folder (Second Job)
| |--|tf_python_job.tf---------------   |
| |--|tf_python.json        |        
| |--|tf_python_check.json  |
| |--|terraform_2.py        |--------> Second job artifacts with config file
| |--|terraform_3.py        |
| |--|terraform_4.py        |
| |--|terraform_5.py        |
| |--|variables.tf--------------------- |
| |backend.tf
| |main.tf
| |provider.tf
| |variables.tf
|.gitlab-ci.yml


The main.tf contains the module resource based on that the module will be captured. But in my case, it is erroring out as below when i execute the .gitlab-ci.yml script.
Error: Failed to download module
   on main.tf line 18:
   18: module "tf_json_job" {
Could not download module "tf_json_job" (main.tf:18) source code from
"git::ssh://git@kochsource.io/molex-data-services/mlx-glue-etl-tf-project.git":
error downloading
'ssh://git@kochsource.io/molex-data-services/mlx-glue-etl-tf-project.git':
/usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into
'.terraform/modules/tf_json_job'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I tried to fix by changing the module source as below,
1st try:
 
source = "git::git@kochsource.io:molex-data-services/mlx-glue-etl-tf-project.git//tf_prj/jobs/tf_json_job
 
2nd try:
 
source = "git::git@kochsource.io:molex-data-services/mlx-glue-etl-tf-project.git//tf_prj/jobs/tf_json_job?ref=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
 


#1 Try directly the script wihtout gitlab and share the results #2 Try again. Sometimes  the download error could be temporary #3 Share a reproducible   or hello world example of your terraform scripts, with focus in the error
